# attempt to Invoke virtual function on a null object reference

Tags: android

Actually my MainActivity has four `fragments`. And i am trying to play the animation on  1st `fragment` of MainActivity the error is :

> " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)'
>   on a null object reference"

below is my code :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    createFragmentOne()
    nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    nav.setItemIconTintList(null)
    try{
        var sep :TextView?
        sep = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sepratesection)
        var anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.blink)
        sep.startAnimation(anim)
    }
    catch (e : Exception)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

`TextView` is in First `Fragment` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: "`TextView` is in First `Fragment` ." – Then you should be handling it in the `Fragment`, rather than in the `Activity`.

Comment: yea got it Thanks!! @MikeM.

Answer (score 1):

You try this with kotlin so try directly like

sepratesection .startAnimation(anim)